# Xamarin custom multiple choice listview

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I was wondering if there is a way to make a multi choice list view that is actually able to return the selected indexes. I've been able to do it with the pre-made multiplechoicelistview adapter but I need to be able to edit the style of it. So I need a custom listview. 
This is my oncreate code a

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Options);
        outList = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.outList);
        var btnCheck = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.btnConfirm);
        var btnBack = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.btnBack);
        for (int i = 0; i < NewProfileVars.LifeStyles.Length; i++)
        {
            inList.Add(NewProfileVars.LifeStyles[i].Name);
        }


        //list contents end here

        ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, inList);
        outList.Adapter = adapter;
        outList.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Multiple;
        NewProfile main = new NewProfile();
        btnCheck.Click += Confirm;
        btnBack.Click += Back;


    }
```

And here is my list view adaptor code

```
    class ListViewAdapter: BaseAdapter<string>
    {
        public List<string> Items;
        public Context Context;

        public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<string> items)
        {
            Items = items;
            Context = context;
        }


        public override int Count
        {
            get { return Items.Count; }
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;

        }
        public override string this[int position]
        {
            get { return Items[position]; }
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View row = convertView;

            if (row == null)
            {
                row = LayoutInflater.From(Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.ListBox, null, false);

            }
            CheckBox txtName = row.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.cbName);
            txtName.Text = Items[position];
            return row;
        }
    }
```

All I need now is to figure out how that confirm button would save the things I have selected.
Thank you in advanced for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see you are using `CheckBox` in your ListView. You could get the Items that where `Checked` using something like this:

First create a class that will hold your item data and the Checked state, for the example let's call it

```
public class LifeStylesListItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public LifeStylesListItem(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Then modify your `ListViewAdapter`

Add a new private field that will hold a list of LifeStylesListItem

```
private List<LifeStylesListItem> _list;
```

Initialize the list with the Items passed in the constructor.

```
public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<string> items)
{
    Items = items;
    _list = new List<LifeStylesListItem>();

    //Your are creating a copy of your Items
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        _list.Add(new LifeStylesListItem(item));
    }

    Context = context;
}
```

In the `GetView` method subscribe to the `CheckedChange` event of your CheckBox. This way you will be notify when it's checked state has changed. Also you need to set the Checked Property based on the Item IsSelected value. This is necessary when the ListView will reuse your cell.

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;

    if (row == null)
    {
        row = LayoutInflater.From(Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.ListBox, null, false);

    }
    CheckBox txtName = row.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.cbName);
    txtName.Text = _list[position].Name;
    txtName.Checked = _list[position].IsSelected;

    txtName.CheckedChange -= TxtName_CheckedChange;
    txtName.CheckedChange += TxtName_CheckedChange;

    return row;
}
```

Add the event handler `TxtName_CheckedChange` method

```
void TxtName_CheckedChange(object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e)
{
    //These lines are used to get the position of the control that was clicked
    var obj = sender as CheckBox;
    var row = obj?.Parent as View; 
    var parent = row?.Parent as ListView;

    if (parent == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var position = parent.GetPositionForView(row);

    // Once you have the position you can get the item and change
    // its IsSelected
    var item = _list[position];
    item.IsSelected = e.IsChecked;
}
```

Then a last method to add in the Adapter is the one that will return the selected Items. With the help of Linq (`using System.Linq` needs to be added) you can query the selected items like this.

```
public List<string> GetCheckedItems()
{
    return _list
            .Where(a => a.IsSelected)
            .Select(b => b.Name)
            .ToList();
}
```

Now in your Activity you just need to call the `GetCheckedItems` from the ListViewAdapter method on the Confirm button click:

```
private void Confirm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var checkedItems = adapter.GetCheckedItems();
}
```

Remember to change `adapter` as private field in your Activity

```
private ListViewAdapter adapter;
```

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Dude you are a wizard thank you so much this has been bugging me for ages. The list items already belonged to a structure with a boolean so i just made the listview adapter use that structure. 
But again thank you so much.

Comment: Wait do you know how it could work for single choice radio buttons?